# Refreshing the config changes with Spring Cloud Bus

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-boot-actuator

I am building an application using Spring Cloud config server as a centralized location for keeping properties file. And I have multiple client applications getting configuration data from config server.

But instead of manually refreshing each client applications to pull latest changes in properties file after commit I'm using Spring cloud bus and Kafka as a message broker so that all changes broadcast to client application. Below are the pom file and properties file.

ConfigServer :
 pom

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

application.properties :

```
  server.port = 8980
```

bootstrap.properties :

```
   spring.cloud.bus.enabled=true
   spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri= "some path"
```

Config Client :
  pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

application.properties :

```
server.port=8982

spring.cloud.bus.refresh.enabled: true
spring.cloud.bus.env.enabled: true
endpoints.spring.cloud.bus.refresh.enabled: true
endpoints.spring.cloud.bus.env.enabled: true

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoAddPartitions=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=localhost:2181
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9892
```

bootstrap.properties  :

```
    spring.application.name=department-service
    spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8980
    management.security.enabled=false
```

But after making changes to local git repository file and after commiting
when I am trying to pull latest changes using "http://localhost:8982/actuator/bus-refresh" endpoint, it is giving error as below :

```
{
"timestamp": "2019-01-29T08:49:21.569+0000",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/actuator/bus-refresh"
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to include "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=bus-refresh" in your config server application.properties and hit this url

http://localhost:8980/actuator/bus-refresh

Answer (score 2):

You need to include "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=bus-refresh" in your config server application.properties. Afterward, send a **GET** request to this URL **localhost:8012/actuator** to see the available **LINKS** for refreshing the config changes. You will see the JSON below

```
{
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8012/actuator",
        "templated": false
    },
    "busrefresh-destinations": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8012/actuator/busrefresh/{*destinations}",
        "templated": true
    },
    "busrefresh": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8012/actuator/busrefresh",
        "templated": false
    }
}
```

Then you can send a **POST** to this **URL** localhost:8012/actuator/busrefresh